# on:hover to affect selector and its :after part

Tags: css, hover

I've made a chat bubble with css:

```
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
    left: 20%;
width: 250px;
height: 185px;
padding: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: #817F7F solid 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 16.36px;
left: -9px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 7px 9px 7px 0;
border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

I want to color the bubble and the pointy thingy when on `:hover`

```
.bubble:hover  {

background:yellow;    

}
```

only colors the `.bubble`, without `.bubble:after`.

How do I color the `:after` part?

[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sUzPm/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another rule to change the colors within the `:after` pseudo-element on `:hover`:

```
.bubble:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent yellow;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/sUzPm/2)